# Impala COMPUTE STATS returns "InvalidOperationException: alter is not possible"

Tags: hive, impala

When using COMPUTE STATS command on any table in my environment i am getting:

```
[impala-node] > compute stats table1; 
Query: compute stats table1
WARNINGS: 
ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'alter_partitions' RPC to Hive Metastore: 
CAUSED BY: InvalidOperationException: alter is not possible
```

All other commands works: `ALTER, CREATE, REFRESH` etc.

I am using Impala version 2.3.0-cdh5.5.4

I couldn't find any solution\explanation online.
Any Ideas?